# XSLT inject a child <span> into <a> text?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**UPDATE**

I have amended my XSL to be:

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script"></output>
    <template match="/ | node() | @*">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
        </copy>
    </template>
    <template match="@class[.='cta-button-secondary']">  
        <attribute name="class">cta-button secondary</attribute>
        <element name="span" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <value-of select=".." />
        </element>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Which almost achieves my needs apart from the `<a>` text being duplicated. I want the anchor text that I have copied within the new child `<span>` and want to discard the duplicate value that remains.

Any advice?

---

How do I use XSLT to inject a `<span>` around the text within an `<a>` element?

XLST:

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" cdata-section-elements="script">  </output>

  <template match="/ | node() | @*">
    <copy>
      <apply-templates select="node() | @*"></apply-templates>
    </copy>
  </template>

  <template match="*[      (self::br or self::p or self::div)     and      normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;     and      not(@*)     and      not(processing-instruction())     and      not(comment())     and      not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])     and      not(following::node()[not(         (self::text() or self::br or self::p or self::div)        and         normalize-space(translate(., &apos; &apos;, &apos;&apos;)) = &apos;&apos;        and         not(@*)        and         not(processing-instruction())        and         not(comment())        and         not(*[not(self::br) or @* or * or node()])       )])     ]">
    <!-- ignore all paragraphs and line-breaks at the end that have nothing but (non-breaking) spaces and line breaks -->
  </template>

  <template match="br[parent::div and not(preceding-sibling::node()) and not(following-sibling::node())]">
    <!-- Chrome generates <div><br/></div>. Renders differently in different browsers. Replace it with a non-breaking space -->
    <text> </text>
  </template>

  <template match="@class[.='cta-button-secondary']">  
    <attribute name="class">cta-button cta-button-secondary</attribute>
  </template>

  <template match="a[@class(contains('cta-button'))]">
    <span>
      <copy-of select="."/>
    </span>
  </template>

</stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<Content xmlns="uuid:3f71252b-6e99-47f2-8906-ff4488c188a1">
  <step_title>Expand our impact</step_title>
  <heading_line_1>Expand our impact</heading_line_1>
  <title_emphasis>Line 1</title_emphasis>
  <intro_text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labasdsadore et dolore magna
    aliqua.c</intro_text>
  <expand_button_label>More about this</expand_button_label>
  <body>
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">How we spent it</h3>
    <ol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ordered">
      <li>ordered list item 1</li>
      <li>ordered list item 2</li>
      <li>ordered list item 3</li>
      <li>ordered list item 4</li>
      <li>ordered list item 5</li>
      <li>ordered list item 6</li>
      <li>ordered list item 7</li>
      <li>ordered list item 8</li>
      <li>ordered list item 9</li>
      <li>ordered list item 10</li>
      <li>ordered list item 11</li>
      <li>ordered list item 12</li>
    </ol>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Thanks to the hard work of our supporters we increased what we spent on cancer services to a
      record £105.9 million in 2011. That's £10 million more than in 2010.</p>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">For a full breakdown of these charts, take a look at our <a href="#">Annual report and accounts
        2011</a> or <a href="#" class="cta-button-secondary">Our 2011 achievements.</a></p>
  </body>
  <quote xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:5-13343" xlink:title="Quote2"/>
  <right_column_image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="tcm:5-13350"
    xlink:title="Wise with money graph"/>
</Content>
```

I expected to be able to have a `<template match="" >` with a `<span><copy-of select="."/></span>` as a child for this but it doesn't seem to work.

I have researched but XSLT is not something I am familiar with and after trying several ways of achieving this I am stuck. I have tried `<apply-templates />`, `<value-of />`, and `<copy-of />` without success.

Comment: When you sau "It doesn't work" do you mean you are getting an error, or that it is not outputing what you expect? In either case, can you show your current output? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stylesheet you have written declares a default namespace with a URI of `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` and no others, so you cannot refer to any elements in any of the namespaces in your source data.

Basically you need to specify all the namespaces you are using in the stylesheet, otherwise the element names you are using won't be recognised. `a` for instance has a namespace

There are three namespaces in the source document and one in the stylesheet (for XSLT itself) so your transform should start with something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:src="uuid:3f71252b-6e99-47f2-8906-ff4488c188a1"
    xmlns:htm="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Thereafter you can refer to the HTML nodes separately from the others by using `htm:div` etc.

I tried to tidy up your XSLT, but the code is dreadful and I cannot fathom what the enormous `match` patterns are supposed to mean in your templates. Suffice to say that you should be able to match the `a` elements you want to affect by using

```
<xsl:template match="htm:a[contains(@class, 'cta-button')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <htm:span>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </htm:span>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I hopes this helps.

Comment: Where I have XML for '<Content><body><a class="cta-button">Anchor Text</a></body></Content>'

I want to get '<Content><body><a class="cta-button"><span>Anchor Text</span></a></body></Content>'.

This solution seems to move the entire '<a>' element within a span but I want the '<span>' within the '<a>' but outside of the '<a>' value.

Comment: Ah OK. Then you want `value-of` instead of `copy-of`. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: <template match="h:a[contains(@class, 'cta-button-secondary')]">
        <copy-of select=".">
            <element name="span" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <value-of select="." />
            </element>
        </copy>
    </template>

The above XSL almost gets me there but the anchor element is missing the href attribute and class attribute etc. Otherwise this works. Why are the attributes not included with the <copy>?

Comment: `xsl:copy` copies only the element node. `xsl:copy-of` copies the node and all its children and attributes. Sorry, I forgot about the attributes. I've fixed my answer again.

Comment: You would save yourself a lot of trouble if you didn't have XSLT as the default namespace. It is very unusual to see code written like that and it means you have to specify the output namespaces explicitly in every case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you getting a little bit mixed up with the namespaces.
You try to avoid prefixes for xlst with

```
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

I would not do that, but any way.
Your `<a>` tag is form xhtml namespace because of

```
 <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

in your xml.

If you try to stay with xslt as default namespace you have to add a namespace prefix for xhtml to your xsl.

```
   xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

Now you can match your a tag with:

```
<template match="h:a">
```

Also the span can't be use without namespace (because it is not xlst). You can
use:

```
<element name="span" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <copy-of select="."/>
</element>
```

**But I would recommend to use a namespace prefix for xslt.**

Update:
To have the span only around  a with class attribute which contains 'cta-button' use:

```
<template match="h:a[@class[contains(.,'cta-button')]]">
    <element name="span" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <copy-of select="."/>
    </element>
</template>
```

The stylesheet should look like:

```
<stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            exclude-result-prefixes="h"
            version="1.0">
```

Comment: Once you've defined `xmlns:h` you can just use `<h:span>`

Comment: `[@class[contains(.,'cta-button')]]` is normally written `[contains(@class,'cta-button')]`

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks, but using the `<h:span>` I was not able to suppress the `h:`prefix.

Comment: You need to set the default namespace in the output to XHTML.